# marshmallow permissions dialog ALLOW button not working why?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I have integrated marshmallow permissions dialog according to new material design, but permission dialog is working on emulator but not on real device. and also i am not getting any error. can any one please help me?

I am using below code:-

ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);

Comment: paste your code here.

Comment: Show your try to get result

Comment: can you check now, i have added code above

Comment: Try this it may be help you:-http://stackoverflow.com/a/41221852/5488468

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a problem with your code....

I had the same problem and was able to fix it with the help of [a similar stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37829165/allow-button-not-working-after-update).

## Solution

Force stopping [this application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rhmsoft.fm) will make the permission dialog allow buttons to work again.

Comment: thatk you so much, after disabling that application its works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

I do this what it may be useful to u

```
                    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) && ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)) {
                        showDialogOK("Phone State & Call Phone Services Permission required for this app",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        switch (which) {
                                            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                                checkAndRequestPermissions();
                                                break;
                                            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                                // proceed with logic by disabling the related features or quit the app.
                                                finish();
                                                break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                    }
```

showDialog method and its work me for CALL_PHONE and  READ_PHONE_STATE

```
private void showDialogOK(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", okListener)
            .create()
            .show();
}
```

Comment: i have done same but still not working thank you for answer